# how to use the setPathSpec in the jetty ConstraintMapping

Tags: java, security, jetty

I'm struggling to get my application properly authorized. I'm having different request paths for my requests like:  localhost:8080//myapp/forFree/xxx  and  localhost:8080//myapp/payed/xxx

I would like to apply different jetty constraintMappings for these urls in order to differentiate access based upon the users role.

During setup I found out that there is hardly any decent documentation around for the jetty security package. At least I couldn't find it. If someone knows the location of the proper documentation please let me know!

Here's my problem:  when I define my Constraint like this:

```
<jaas:config name="tueInstitutionLdap" rank="1">
    <jaas:module className="nl.caci.osiris.common.login.module.LdapLoginModule"
        flags="required" />
</jaas:config>

<bean id="tueLoginService" class="org.eclipse.jetty.plus.jaas.JAASLoginService">
    <property name="name" value="xxxxxxx" />
    <property name="loginModuleName" value="tueInstitutionLdap" />
    <property name="roleClassNames">
        <list>
            <value>java.security.Identity</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="tueIdentityService" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.DefaultIdentityService" />

<bean id="beheerConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
    <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
    <property name="roles">
        <list>
            <value>beheerder</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="mapping1" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
    <property name="constraint" ref="beheerderConstraint" />
    <property name="pathSpec" value="/*" />
</bean>

<bean id="tueSecurityHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
    <property name="authenticator">
        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator" />
    </property>
    <property name="constraintMappings">
        <list>
            <ref component-id="mapping1" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="strict" value="true" />
    <property name="identityService" ref="tueIdentityService" />
    <property name="loginService" ref="tueLoginService" />
</bean>
```

This setup will cause the browser to prompt for a userid and password, authenticates the user and will provide access to ALL request when the user has the role "beheerder". Since I want to differenciate acces to the requests I made the following changes to this setup:

```
<bean id="beheerderConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
    <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
    <property name="roles">
        <list>
            <value>beheerder</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="studentConstraint" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.security.Constraint">
    <property name="name" value="BASIC" />
    <property name="roles">
        <list>
            <value>studenten</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticate" value="true" />
</bean>

<bean id="mapping1" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
    <property name="constraint" ref="beheerderConstraint" />
    <property name="pathSpec" value="/myapp/payed/*" />
</bean>

<bean id="mapping2" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintMapping">
    <property name="constraint" ref="studentConstraint" />
    <property name="pathSpec" value="/myapp/forFree/*" />
</bean> 

<bean id="tueSecurityHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
    <property name="authenticator">
        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator" />
    </property>
    <property name="constraintMappings">
        <list>
            <ref component-id="mapping1" />
            <ref component-id="mapping2" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="strict" value="true" />
    <property name="identityService" ref="tueIdentityService" />
    <property name="loginService" ref="tueLoginService" />
</bean>
....
```

And now I run into problems. I get access to all request, there is no prompt for a userid and password anymore, no authentication and no authorization is applied any more.
Is  a valid path?? I Can't find any proper documentation on this class/ method. I found some samples that also use these kind of paths though.
Is this the proper way to assigng different roles to different request paths?

I'm using a Redhat JBOSS Fuse 6.2.0 environment to run my camel routes.
Any help is appreciated..

Regards,

Jan van de Klok